# How to call the constructor of a derived class without calling the constructor of the base class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, constructor, member

I was refreshing my limited knowledge of inheritance in c# 11 because I need it for a project. However I got unexpected results when calling the constructor of an inherited class. Any call to the inherited constructor always resulted in a call to base constructor first. I was under the impression that the normal way to call the base constructor before the inherited constructor is to do the following:

```
internal DerivedClass()
: base()
{
   // Do stuff here. Behaves as expected
}
```

However the same functionality is achieved without the `: base()`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new BaseClass(); // Prints "BaseClass". Behaves as expected
        new DerivedClass(); // Prints "BaseClass"\n"DerivedClass". Expected behavior: "DerivedClass"
        new DerivedClass("test"); // Prints "BaseClass"\n"test". Expected behavior: "test"
    }
}

class BaseClass
{
    internal BaseClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass");
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    internal DerivedClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass");
    }

    internal DerivedClass(string test) // Different parameters than BaseClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
}
```

So how do I call the constructor of a derived class without constructor chaining? I thank anyone answering in advance.

What I did so far:

- Confirming the described execution flow with the dotnet debugger
- Searching the web (no relevant results)
- Searching StackOverflow (no relevant results)
- Reading the Microsoft [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/inheritance) on inheritance (not useful for this problem and the publication example had ambiguity errors out of the box (it wasn't relevant to this problem anyway))
- I am currently in Italy and OpenAI blocks ProtonVPN so I currently have no access to ChatGPT

Comment: your expected behavior doesnt have relation with your code. I think the error is in the basic understanding of OOP

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Could you please elaborate what you're suggesting? What I mean with expected behavior is what I would expect the called constructor to print to the command line (this is a simplified example after all) based on the code, i.e. with the expression `new DerivedClass();` I would expect the constructor of DerivedClass to be called and which then prints "DerivedClass" to the console with `Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass");`.  What happened instead is that this expression first called the constructor of BaseClass and printed "BaseClass" before calling the BaseClass` constructor.

Comment: @DogPerson that's how the OOP works, the base class constructor is always called

Comment: You can actually do this in VB.NET: do stuff in the derived constructor before the base one. But the base must always be called at some point.

Comment: [C# Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors). Note the steps that it lays out and in what order. Note that it doesn't indicate that any of them are optional. Note that step 4 is running the base class constructors.